# EF4 Dependent object won't return data for extended fields in TPT

Tags: vb.net, wcf, entity-framework-4, poco

I am using TPT modeling and writing the EDMX by hand as our data model is much more complex than the designer can support. My model includes a ProjectObject which has a dependent object name Project. When I query ProjectObject.OfType(Project) using Linq to SQL, I receive back data in all the fields that are inherited from ProjectObject, but no data in the fields that only in Project. I have ran a SQL Server Trace and captured the actual SQL and ran it using SSMS and it returns data there, so I am relatively certain the data is being passed back, but it seems to be getting lost somewhere in EF. Everything appears to be ok in my model, but . . .

SSDL

```
        <EntityContainer Name="Insight_ModelStoreContainer">
            <EntitySet Name="Project" EntityType="Insight_Model.Store.Project" store:Type="Views" store:Schema="dbo" store:Name="vw_insight_Project">
                <DefiningQuery>
                    SELECT
                    [vw_insight_Project].[ProjNum] AS [ProjNum],
                    [vw_insight_Project].[ID] AS [ID],
                    [vw_insight_Project].[RefID] AS [RefID],
                    [vw_insight_Project].[Name] AS [Name],
                    [vw_insight_Project].[TypeID] AS [TypeID],
                    [vw_insight_Project].[ClientUserID] AS [ClientUserID],
                    [vw_insight_Project].[ClientCompanyLocID] AS [ClientCompanyLocID],
                    [vw_insight_Project].[ClientCompanyID] AS [ClientCompanyID],
                    [vw_insight_Project].[CustomerUserID] AS [CustomerUserID],
                    [vw_insight_Project].[CustomerCompanyLocID] AS [CustomerCompanyLocID],
                    [vw_insight_Project].[CustomerCompanyID] AS [CustomerCompanyID],
                    [vw_insight_Project].[DistributorUserID] AS [DistributorUserID],
                    [vw_insight_Project].[DistributorCompanyLocID] AS [DistributorCompanyLocID],
                    [vw_insight_Project].[DistributorCompanyID] AS [DistributorCompanyID],
                    [vw_insight_Project].[TechUserID] AS [TechUserID],
                    [vw_insight_Project].[TechCompanyLocID] AS [TechCompanyLocID],
                    [vw_insight_Project].[TechCompanyID] AS [TechCompanyID],
                    [vw_insight_Project].[EmployeeUserID] AS [EmployeeUserID],
                    [vw_insight_Project].[EmployeeCompanyLocID] AS [EmployeeCompanyLocID],
                    [vw_insight_Project].[EmployeeCompanyID] AS [EmployeeCompanyID],
                    [vw_insight_Project].[VendorUserID] AS [VendorUserID],
                    [vw_insight_Project].[VendorCompanyLocID] AS [VendorCompanyLocID],
                    [vw_insight_Project].[VendorCompanyID] AS [VendorCompanyID],
                    [vw_insight_Project].[CreateDate] AS [CreateDate],
                    [vw_insight_Project].[ModifyDate] AS [ModifyDate],
                    [vw_insight_Project].[CreateUID] AS [CreateUID],
                    [vw_insight_Project].[ModifyUID] AS [ModifyUID]
                    FROM [dbo].[vw_insight_Project] AS [vw_insight_Project]
                </DefiningQuery>
            </EntitySet>
        </EntityContainer>
        <EntityType Name="Project">
            <Key>
                <PropertyRef Name="ID" />
            </Key>
            <Property Name="ProjNum" Type="int" Nullable="false"/>
            <Property Name="ID" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
            <Property Name="RefID" Type="int" />
            <Property Name="Name" Type="varchar" Nullable="false" MaxLength="50" />
            <Property Name="TypeID" Type="int" />
            <Property Name="ClientUserID" Type="int" Nullable="true" />
            <Property Name="ClientCompanyLocID" Type="int" Nullable="true" />
            <Property Name="ClientCompanyID" Type="int" Nullable="true" />
            <Property Name="CustomerUserID" Type="int" Nullable="true" />
            <Property Name="CustomerCompanyLocID" Type="int" Nullable="true" />
            <Property Name="CustomerCompanyID" Type="int" Nullable="true" />
            <Property Name="DistributorUserID" Type="int" Nullable="true" />
            <Property Name="DistributorCompanyLocID" Type="int" Nullable="true" />
            <Property Name="DistributorCompanyID" Type="int" Nullable="true" />
            <Property Name="TechUserID" Type="int" Nullable="true" />
            <Property Name="TechCompanyLocID" Type="int" Nullable="true" />
            <Property Name="TechCompanyID" Type="int" Nullable="true" />
            <Property Name="EmployeeUserID" Type="int" />
            <Property Name="EmployeeCompanyLocID" Type="int" Nullable="true" />
            <Property Name="EmployeeCompanyID" Type="int" Nullable="true" />
            <Property Name="VendorUserID" Type="int" Nullable="true" />
            <Property Name="VendorCompanyLocID" Type="int" Nullable="true" />
            <Property Name="VendorCompanyID" Type="int" Nullable="true" />
            <Property Name="CreateDate" Type="date" Nullable="false" />
            <Property Name="ModifyDate" Type="date" Nullable="false" />
            <Property Name="CreateUID" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
            <Property Name="ModifyUID" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
        </EntityType>
```

CSDL

```
            <EntityContainer Name="Insight_Entities" annotation:LazyLoadingEnabled="true">
                <EntitySet Name="ProjectObjects" EntityType="Insight_Model.ProjectObject" />
            </EntityContainer>
            <EntityType Name="ProjectObject" Abstract="true">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="ID" />
                </Key>
                <Property Type="Int32" Name="ProjNum" Nullable="false" />
                <Property Type="Int32" Name="ID" Nullable="false" annotation:StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
                <Property Type="Int32" Name="RefID" />
                <Property Type="String" Name="Name" Nullable="false" MaxLength="50" FixedLength="false" Unicode="false" />
                <Property Type="Int32" Name="TypeID" Nullable="false" />
                <Property Type="DateTime" Name="CreateDate" Nullable="false" />
                <Property Type="DateTime" Name="ModifyDate" Nullable="false" />
                <Property Type="Int32" Name="CreateUID" Nullable="false" />
                <Property Type="Int32" Name="ModifyUID" Nullable="false" />
                <NavigationProperty Name="UserRoles" Relationship="Insight_Model.UserRoleProjectObject" FromRole="ProjectObject" ToRole="UserRole" />
                <NavigationProperty Name="ProjectObjectComments" Relationship="Insight_Model.ProjectObjectComments" FromRole="ProjectObject" ToRole="CommentProjectObject" />
                <NavigationProperty Name="ProjectObjectFollowUps" Relationship="Insight_Model.ProjectObjectFollowUps" FromRole="ProjectObject" ToRole="FollowUpProjectObject" />
                <NavigationProperty Name="ProjectObjectAttachments" Relationship="Insight_Model.ProjectObjectAttachments" FromRole="ProjectObject" ToRole="AttachmentProjectObject" />
                <NavigationProperty Name="ProjectObjectType" Relationship="Insight_Model.ProjectObjectTypeAttributeLookup" FromRole="ProjectObject" ToRole="AttributeLookup" />
            </EntityType>
            <EntityType Name="Project" BaseType="Insight_Model.ProjectObject" >
                <Property Type="Int32" Name="ClientUserID" />
                <Property Type="Int32" Name="ClientCompanyLocID" />
                <Property Type="Int32" Name="ClientCompanyID" />
                <Property Type="Int32" Name="CustomerUserID" />
                <Property Type="Int32" Name="CustomerCompanyLocID" />
                <Property Type="Int32" Name="CustomerCompanyID" />
                <Property Type="Int32" Name="DistributorUserID" />
                <Property Type="Int32" Name="DistributorCompanyLocID" />
                <Property Type="Int32" Name="DistributorCompanyID" />
                <Property Type="Int32" Name="TechUserID" />
                <Property Type="Int32" Name="TechCompanyLocID" />
                <Property Type="Int32" Name="TechCompanyID" />
                <Property Type="Int32" Name="EmployeeUserID" />
                <Property Type="Int32" Name="EmployeeCompanyLocID" />
                <Property Type="Int32" Name="EmployeeCompanyID" />
                <Property Type="Int32" Name="VendorUserID" />
                <Property Type="Int32" Name="VendorCompanyLocID" />
                <Property Type="Int32" Name="VendorCompanyID" />
                <NavigationProperty Name="ClientUserRole" Relationship="Insight_Model.ProjectClientUserRole" FromRole="Project" ToRole="UserRole" />
                <NavigationProperty Name="CustomerUserRole" Relationship="Insight_Model.ProjectCustomerUserRole" FromRole="Project" ToRole="UserRole" />
                <NavigationProperty Name="DistributorUserRole" Relationship="Insight_Model.ProjectDistributorUserRole" FromRole="Project" ToRole="UserRole" />
                <NavigationProperty Name="TechUserRole" Relationship="Insight_Model.ProjectTechUserRole" FromRole="Project" ToRole="UserRole" />
                <NavigationProperty Name="EmployeeUserRole" Relationship="Insight_Model.ProjectEmployeeUserRole" FromRole="Project" ToRole="UserRole" />
                <NavigationProperty Name="VendorUserRole" Relationship="Insight_Model.ProjectVendorUserRole" FromRole="Project" ToRole="UserRole" />
                <NavigationProperty Name="ClientCompany" Relationship="Insight_Model.ProjectClientCompany" FromRole="Project" ToRole="Company" />
                <NavigationProperty Name="CustomerCompany" Relationship="Insight_Model.ProjectCustomerCompany" FromRole="Project" ToRole="Company" />
                <NavigationProperty Name="DistributorCompany" Relationship="Insight_Model.ProjectDistributorCompany" FromRole="Project" ToRole="Company" />
                <NavigationProperty Name="TechCompany" Relationship="Insight_Model.ProjectTechCompany" FromRole="Project" ToRole="Company" />
                <NavigationProperty Name="EmployeeCompany" Relationship="Insight_Model.ProjectEmployeeCompany" FromRole="Project" ToRole="Company" />
                <NavigationProperty Name="VendorCompany" Relationship="Insight_Model.ProjectVendorCompany" FromRole="Project" ToRole="Company" />
                <NavigationProperty Name="ClientCompanyLoc" Relationship="Insight_Model.ProjectClientCompanyLoc" FromRole="Project" ToRole="CompanyLoc" />
                <NavigationProperty Name="CustomerCompanyLoc" Relationship="Insight_Model.ProjectCustomerCompanyLoc" FromRole="Project" ToRole="CompanyLoc" />
                <NavigationProperty Name="DistributorCompanyLoc" Relationship="Insight_Model.ProjectDistributorCompanyLoc" FromRole="Project" ToRole="CompanyLoc" />
                <NavigationProperty Name="TechCompanyLoc" Relationship="Insight_Model.ProjectTechCompanyLoc" FromRole="Project" ToRole="CompanyLoc" />
                <NavigationProperty Name="EmployeeCompanyLoc" Relationship="Insight_Model.ProjectEmployeeCompanyLoc" FromRole="Project" ToRole="CompanyLoc" />
                <NavigationProperty Name="VendorCompanyLoc" Relationship="Insight_Model.ProjectVendorCompanyLoc" FromRole="Project" ToRole="CompanyLoc" />
            </EntityType>
```

CSDL

```
                <EntitySetMapping Name="ProjectObjects">
                    <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="Insight_Model.Project" >
                        <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="Project">
                            <ScalarProperty Name="ProjNum" ColumnName="ProjNum" />
                            <ScalarProperty Name="RefID" ColumnName="RefID" />
                            <ScalarProperty Name="ID" ColumnName="ID" />
                            <ScalarProperty Name="Name" ColumnName="Name" />
                            <ScalarProperty Name="TypeID" ColumnName="TypeID" />
                            <ScalarProperty Name="CreateUID" ColumnName="CreateUID" />
                            <ScalarProperty Name="ModifyUID" ColumnName="ModifyUID" />
                            <ScalarProperty Name="CreateDate" ColumnName="CreateDate" />
                            <ScalarProperty Name="ModifyDate" ColumnName="ModifyDate" />
                            <ScalarProperty Name="ClientUserID" ColumnName="ClientUserID" />
                            <ScalarProperty Name="ClientCompanyLocID" ColumnName="ClientCompanyLocID" />
                            <ScalarProperty Name="ClientCompanyID" ColumnName="ClientCompanyID" />
                            <ScalarProperty Name="CustomerUserID" ColumnName="CustomerUserID" />
                            <ScalarProperty Name="CustomerCompanyLocID" ColumnName="CustomerCompanyLocID" />
                            <ScalarProperty Name="CustomerCompanyID" ColumnName="CustomerCompanyID" />
                            <ScalarProperty Name="DistributorUserID" ColumnName="DistributorUserID" />
                            <ScalarProperty Name="DistributorCompanyLocID" ColumnName="DistributorCompanyLocID" />
                            <ScalarProperty Name="DistributorCompanyID" ColumnName="DistributorCompanyID" />
                            <ScalarProperty Name="TechUserID" ColumnName="TechUserID" />
                            <ScalarProperty Name="TechCompanyLocID" ColumnName="TechCompanyLocID" />
                            <ScalarProperty Name="TechCompanyID" ColumnName="TechCompanyID" />
                            <ScalarProperty Name="EmployeeUserID" ColumnName="EmployeeUserID" />
                            <ScalarProperty Name="EmployeeCompanyLocID" ColumnName="EmployeeCompanyLocID" />
                            <ScalarProperty Name="EmployeeCompanyID" ColumnName="EmployeeCompanyID" />
                            <ScalarProperty Name="VendorUserID" ColumnName="VendorUserID" />
                            <ScalarProperty Name="VendorCompanyLocID" ColumnName="VendorCompanyLocID" />
                            <ScalarProperty Name="VendorCompanyID" ColumnName="VendorCompanyID" />
                        </MappingFragment>
                    </EntityTypeMapping>
                </EntitySetMapping>
```

And the POCO that stores the data

```
#Region "ProjectObject"
''' <summary>
''' ProjectObject class.
''' </summary>
<Serializable()>
<DataContractAttribute(IsReference:=True)>
<KnownTypeAttribute(GetType(Project))>
<KnownTypeAttribute(GetType(WorkOrder))>
<KnownTypeAttribute(GetType(Survey))>
Partial Public MustInherit Class ProjectObject
#Region "Declarations"
    Private _ProjNum As Global.System.Int32
    Private _ID As Global.System.Int32
    Private _RefID As Nullable(Of Global.System.Int32)
    Private _TypeID As Global.System.Int32
    Private _Name As Global.System.String
    Private _CreateDate As Global.System.DateTime
    Private _ModifyDate As Global.System.DateTime
    Private _CreateUID As Global.System.Int32
    Private _ModifyUID As Global.System.Int32
    Private _ParentObject As ProjectObject
    Private _UserRoles As ObservableCollection(Of UserRole)
    Private _ChildObjects As ICollection(Of ProjectObject)
    Private _ProjectObjectAttributes As ICollection(Of ProjectObjectAttribute)
    Private _ProjectObjectComments As ObservableCollection(Of CommentProjectObject)
    Private _ProjectObjectAttachments As ObservableCollection(Of AttachmentProjectObject)
    Private _ProjectObjectFollowUps As IObservable(Of FollowUpProjectObject)
    Private _ProjectObjectType As AttributeLookup
#End Region
#Region "Primitive Properties"
#Region "ProjNum"
    ''' <summary>Project Number.</summary>
    <DataMemberAttribute()>
    Public Property ProjNum() As Global.System.Int32
        Get
            Return _ProjNum
        End Get
        Set(value As Global.System.Int32)
            If (_ProjNum <> value) Then
                OnProjNumChanging(value)
                _ProjNum = value
                OnProjNumChanged()
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Partial Private Sub OnProjNumChanging(value As Global.System.Int32)
    End Sub

    Partial Private Sub OnProjNumChanged()
    End Sub
#End Region
#Region "ID"
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Project Object ID.
    ''' </summary>
    <DataMemberAttribute()>
    Public Property ID() As Global.System.Int32
        Get
            Return _ID
        End Get
        Set(value As Global.System.Int32)
            If (_ID <> value) Then
                OnIDChanging(value)
                _ID = value
                OnIDChanged()
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Partial Private Sub OnIDChanging(value As Global.System.Int32)
    End Sub

    Partial Private Sub OnIDChanged()
    End Sub
#End Region
#Region "RefID"
    ''' <summary>
    ''' No Metadata Documentation available.
    ''' </summary>
    <DataMemberAttribute()>
    Public Property RefID() As Nullable(Of Global.System.Int32)
        Get
            Return _RefID
        End Get
        Set(value As Nullable(Of Global.System.Int32))
            OnRefIDChanging(value)
            _RefID = value
            OnRefIDChanged()
        End Set
    End Property

    Partial Private Sub OnRefIDChanging(value As Nullable(Of Global.System.Int32))
    End Sub

    Partial Private Sub OnRefIDChanged()
    End Sub
#End Region
#Region "Name"
    ''' <summary>
    ''' No Metadata Documentation available.
    ''' </summary>
    <DataMemberAttribute()>
    Public Property Name() As Global.System.String
        Get
            Return _Name
        End Get
        Set(value As Global.System.String)
            OnNameChanging(value)
            _Name = value
            OnNameChanged()
        End Set
    End Property

    Partial Private Sub OnNameChanging(value As Global.System.String)
    End Sub

    Partial Private Sub OnNameChanged()
    End Sub
#End Region
#Region "TypeID"
    ''' <summary>
    ''' TypeID.
    ''' </summary>
    <DataMemberAttribute()>
    Public Property TypeID() As Global.System.Int32
        Get
            Return _TypeID
        End Get
        Set(value As Global.System.Int32)
            If (_TypeID <> value) Then
                OnTypeIDChanging(value)
                _TypeID = value
                OnTypeIDChanged()
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Partial Private Sub OnTypeIDChanging(value As Global.System.Int32)
    End Sub

    Partial Private Sub OnTypeIDChanged()
    End Sub
#End Region
'Remaining primitives removed for brevity.
#End Region
#Region "Navigation Properties"
#Region "ParentObject"
    <DataMemberAttribute()>
    <XmlIgnoreAttribute()>
    <SoapIgnoreAttribute()>
    Public Overridable Property ParentObject() As ProjectObject
        Get
            Return _ParentObject
        End Get
        Set(value As ProjectObject)
            _ParentObject = value
        End Set
    End Property
#End Region
#Region "UserRoles"
    <DataMemberAttribute()>
    <XmlIgnoreAttribute()>
    <SoapIgnoreAttribute()>
    Public Overridable Property UserRoles() As ObservableCollection(Of UserRole)
        Get
            Return _UserRoles
        End Get
        Set(value As ObservableCollection(Of UserRole))
            _UserRoles = value
        End Set
    End Property
#End Region
#Region "ChildObjects"
    <DataMemberAttribute()>
    <XmlIgnoreAttribute()>
    <SoapIgnoreAttribute()>
    Public Overridable Property ChildObjects() As ICollection(Of ProjectObject)
        Get
            Return _ChildObjects
        End Get
        Set(value As ICollection(Of ProjectObject))
            _ChildObjects = value
        End Set
    End Property
#End Region
#Region "ProjectObjectAttributes"
    <DataMemberAttribute()>
    <XmlIgnoreAttribute()>
    <SoapIgnoreAttribute()>
    Public Overridable Property ProjectObjectAttributes() As ICollection(Of ProjectObjectAttribute)
        Get
            Return _ProjectObjectAttributes
        End Get
        Set(value As ICollection(Of ProjectObjectAttribute))
            _ProjectObjectAttributes = value
        End Set
    End Property
#End Region
#Region "ProjectObjectAttachments"
    <DataMemberAttribute()>
    <XmlIgnoreAttribute()>
    <SoapIgnoreAttribute()>
    Public Overridable Property ProjectObjectAttachments() As IObservable(Of AttachmentProjectObject)
        Get
            Return _ProjectObjectAttachments
        End Get
        Set(value As IObservable(Of AttachmentProjectObject))
            _ProjectObjectAttachments = value
        End Set
    End Property
#End Region
#Region "ProjectObjectFollowUps"
    <DataMemberAttribute()>
    <XmlIgnoreAttribute()>
    <SoapIgnoreAttribute()>
    Public Overridable Property ProjectObjectFollowUps() As IObservable(Of FollowUpProjectObject)
        Get
            Return _ProjectObjectFollowUps
        End Get
        Set(value As IObservable(Of FollowUpProjectObject))
            _ProjectObjectFollowUps = value
        End Set
    End Property
#End Region
#Region "ProjectObjectComments"
    <DataMemberAttribute()>
    <XmlIgnoreAttribute()>
    <SoapIgnoreAttribute()>
    Public Overridable Property ProjectObjectComments() As ObservableCollection(Of CommentProjectObject)
        Get
            Return _ProjectObjectComments
        End Get
        Set(value As ObservableCollection(Of CommentProjectObject))
            _ProjectObjectComments = value
        End Set
    End Property
#End Region
#Region "ProjectObjectType"
    <DataMemberAttribute()>
    <XmlIgnoreAttribute()>
    <SoapIgnoreAttribute()>
    Public Overridable Property ProjectObjectType() As AttributeLookup
        Get
            Return _ProjectObjectType
        End Get
        Set(value As AttributeLookup)
            _ProjectObjectType = value
        End Set
    End Property
#End Region
#End Region
End Class
#End Region
<Serializable()>
<DataContractAttribute(IsReference:=True)>
Partial Public Class Project
    Inherits ProjectObject
#Region "Declarations"
    Private _ProjectID As Global.System.Int32
    Private _ClientUserID As Nullable(Of Global.System.Int32)
    Private _ClientCompanyLocID As Nullable(Of Global.System.Int32)
    Private _ClientCompanyID As Nullable(Of Global.System.Int32)
    Private _CustomerUserID As Nullable(Of Global.System.Int32)
    Private _CustomerCompanyLocID As Nullable(Of Global.System.Int32)
    Private _CustomerCompanyID As Nullable(Of Global.System.Int32)
    Private _DistributorUserID As Nullable(Of Global.System.Int32)
    Private _DistributorCompanyLocID As Nullable(Of Global.System.Int32)
    Private _DistributorCompanyID As Nullable(Of Global.System.Int32)
    Private _TechUserID As Nullable(Of Global.System.Int32)
    Private _TechCompanyLocID As Nullable(Of Global.System.Int32)
    Private _TechCompanyID As Nullable(Of Global.System.Int32)
    Private _EmployeeUserID As Nullable(Of Global.System.Int32)
    Private _EmployeeCompanyLocID As Nullable(Of Global.System.Int32)
    Private _EmployeeCompanyID As Nullable(Of Global.System.Int32)
    Private _VendorUserID As Nullable(Of Global.System.Int32)
    Private _VendorCompanyLocID As Nullable(Of Global.System.Int32)
    Private _VendorCompanyID As Nullable(Of Global.System.Int32)
    Private _ClientUserRole As UserRole
    Private _CustomerUserRole As UserRole
    Private _DistributorUserRole As UserRole
    Private _TechUserRole As UserRole
    Private _EmployeeUserRole As UserRole
    Private _VendorUserRole As UserRole
    Private _ClientCompany As Company
    Private _CustomerCompany As Company
    Private _DistributorCompany As Company
    Private _TechCompany As Company
    Private _EmployeeCompany As Company
    Private _VendorCompany As Company
    Private _ClientCompanyLoc As CompanyLoc
    Private _CustomerCompanyLoc As CompanyLoc
    Private _DistributorCompanyLoc As CompanyLoc
    Private _TechCompanyLoc As CompanyLoc
    Private _EmployeeCompanyLoc As CompanyLoc
    Private _VendorCompanyLoc As CompanyLoc
#End Region
#Region "Primitive Properties"
#Region "ProjectID"
    ''' <summary>ProjectID.</summary>
    <DataMemberAttribute()>
    Public Property ProjectID() As Nullable(Of Global.System.Int32)
        Get
            Return _ProjectID
        End Get
        Set(value As Nullable(Of Global.System.Int32))
            If (_ProjectID <> value) Then
                OnProjectIDChanging(value)
                _ProjectID = value
                OnProjectIDChanged()
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Partial Private Sub OnProjectIDChanging(value As Nullable(Of Global.System.Int32))
    End Sub

    Partial Private Sub OnProjectIDChanged()
    End Sub
#End Region
#Region "ClientUserID"
    ''' <summary>ClientUserID.</summary>
    <DataMemberAttribute()>
    Public Property ClientUserID() As Nullable(Of Global.System.Int32)
        Get
            Return _ClientUserID
        End Get
        Set(value As Nullable(Of Global.System.Int32))
            If (_ClientUserID <> value) Then
                OnClientUserIDChanging(value)
                _ClientUserID = value
                OnClientUserIDChanged()
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Partial Private Sub OnClientUserIDChanging(value As Nullable(Of Global.System.Int32))
    End Sub

    Partial Private Sub OnClientUserIDChanged()
    End Sub
#End Region
#Region "ClientCompanyLocID"
    ''' <summary>ClientCompanyLoc.</summary>
    <DataMemberAttribute()>
    Public Property ClientCompanyLocID() As Nullable(Of Global.System.Int32)
        Get
            Return _ClientCompanyLocID
        End Get
        Set(value As Nullable(Of Global.System.Int32))
            If (_ClientCompanyLocID <> value) Then
                OnClientCompanyLocIDChanging(value)
                _ClientCompanyLocID = value
                OnClientCompanyLocIDChanged()
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Partial Private Sub OnClientCompanyLocIDChanging(value As Nullable(Of Global.System.Int32))
    End Sub

    Partial Private Sub OnClientCompanyLocIDChanged()
    End Sub
#End Region
'Remaining Primitives removed for Brevity
#End Region
#Region "Factory Method"
    'Removed for brevity of posting
#End Region
#Region "Navigation Properties"
#Region "CustomerUserRole"
    <DataMemberAttribute()>
    <XmlIgnoreAttribute()>
    <SoapIgnoreAttribute()>
    Public Overridable Property CustomerUserRole() As UserRole
        Get
            Return _CustomerUserRole
        End Get
        Set(value As UserRole)
            _CustomerUserRole = value
        End Set
    End Property
#End Region
#Region "DistributorUserRole"
    <DataMemberAttribute()>
    <XmlIgnoreAttribute()>
    <SoapIgnoreAttribute()>
    Public Overridable Property DistributorUserRole() As UserRole
        Get
            Return _DistributorUserRole
        End Get
        Set(value As UserRole)
            _DistributorUserRole = value
        End Set
    End Property
#End Region
#Region "EmployeeUserRole"
    <DataMemberAttribute()>
    <XmlIgnoreAttribute()>
    <SoapIgnoreAttribute()>
    Public Overridable Property EmployeeUserRole() As UserRole
        Get
            Return _EmployeeUserRole
        End Get
        Set(value As UserRole)
            _EmployeeUserRole = value
        End Set
    End Property
#End Region
'Remaining navigation properties removed for brevity
#End Region
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason I was not receiving data is because I was checking:

```
If (_ClientCompanyID <> value) Then
```

for each property. What was happening is that it was checking to see if nothing (_ClientCompanyID) was not equal to 1 (value) the net result was always False so the data wasn't stored.

```
Set(value As Nullable(Of Global.System.Int32))
    If (_ClientCompanyID <> value) Then
        OnClientCompanyIDChanging(value)
        _ClientCompanyID = value
        OnClientCompanyIDChanged()
    End If
End Set
```

Should have been:

```
    Set(value As Nullable(Of Global.System.Int32))
            OnClientCompanyIDChanging(value)
            _ClientCompanyID = value
            OnClientCompanyIDChanged()
    End Set
```

for all nullable values. Doh!!! Lesson learned.